# Проблема с кодировкой в mailto (utf-8)

Tags: google-chrome, opera, html, firefox, utf-8

Делал задание по книге O'REILLY "Изучаем PHP и MySQL"

Есть простенькая форма

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body><form method="post" action="mailto:owen@aliensubductedme.com?subject=Похищение людей" enctype="text/plain">
<label for="firstname">Имя:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"/><br/>  
<label for="sunname">Фамилия:</label>
<input/ type="text" id="sunname" name="sunname"><br/>
<label for="more">Дополнительная информация</label>  <textarea id="more" name="more">                      
</textarea><br/> <input type="submit" value="Кнопка подтверждения" name="submit"/>        
</form></body>
```

Когда открываю этот файл в Firefox и отправляю письмо при помощи Mozilla Thunderbird или Microsoft Outlook 2010 - то все отображается нормально.

Ссылка:
http://cs619818.vk.me/v619818687/15db/JmfittOIROA.jpg

Но стоит попытаться отправить через Chrome или Opera как возникают проблемы с кодировкой (при этом тема письма отображается правильно).

Ссылка:
http://cs619818.vk.me/v619818687/15e3/EeBgnaJyRCo.jpg

В чем причина этого и как делать так, что бы в Chrome и Opera письмо отправлялось нормально.

P.S. В файле .htaccess есть запись "CharsetDisable on CharsetDefault utf-8 CharsetSourceEnc utf-8 AddDefaultCharset utf-8
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй добавить в начало документа

```
-*-coding: utf-8 -*-
```

или сохрани в формате utf-8